# npm ERR! Invalid dependency type requested: alias

Tags: node.js, npm

Inherited project says to run `npm install` to install packages for project. But when I do I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Invalid dependency type requested: alias
```

In the log I can see the following messages:

> 212 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for
>   redux-form-7@npm:redux-form@7.3.0 Invalid dependency type requested:
>   alias
>
> ...
>
> 2744 verbose stack Error: Invalid dependency type requested: alias
>
> 2744 verbose stack     at getFetcher (/Users/rich/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetch.js:68:15)
>
> 2744 verbose stack     at manifest (/Users/rich/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetch.js:15:19)
>
> 2744 verbose stack     at pinflight
>   (/Users/rich/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/manifest.js:24:12)
>
> ...

In `package.json` is the following:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "redux-form": "5.3.3",
    "redux-form-7": "npm:redux-form@7.3.0"
  }
}
```

I've googled and searched SO but I can't find what this dependency syntax is meant to do or what the error means?

Answer (score 28):

npm >= 6.9.0 can handle aliases, https://npm.community/t/release-npm-6-9-0/5911.

Comment: Worth to add that in order to fix one should run: `npm install -g npm@latest` and then try to `npm install` again

Comment: This command npm install -g npm@latest itself gives this error

Comment: i try "npm install -g npm@latest" and i have this error: Invalid dependency type requested: alias

Comment: @HVSharma yeap, thats well explained in Raphael Krausz answer below...

Answer (score 9):

**Edit**: at the time of writing, this feature was not supported by npm. See Andrew's answer for which versions of npm now support it.

Original answer:

It seems this is a feature of [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/) and not npm.

Using yarn to install packages worked fine with this package.json.

Answer (score 6):

If you are still having troubles upgrading to the latest version of npm, due to the same "ERR! Invalid dependency type requested: alias" error, then do the following:

1. First install npm v6.9.0.  As previous versions didn't have alias support, it will install fine. Thanks andrewkittredge!

   npm i -g npm@6.9.0
2. Then you can upgrade to the latest version of npm

   npm i -g npm@latest

Comment: Yeap, thats definatelly the correct aproach

Answer (score 0):

Under Mac OS this worked for me

1. Delete the folder /Users/userName/.npm (this is a hidden folder, so you have to unhide hidden folders first with keyboard shortcut "Command" + "Shift" + "." if you want to delete it via the Finder)
2. `sudo npm i -g npm@latest`